# Regex recursive replace in vim when pattern has tilde

Tags: regex, vim

My initial file is

```
192.168.210.12
192.168.210.13
192.168.210.14
192.168.210.15
192.168.210.16
192.168.210.17
192.168.210.18
192.168.210.18
```

Pattern for replance is `%s/\(192.168.210.[0-9]\+\)/\"ssh\ myuser@\1\ -i\ ~\/Documents\/my_key\"/g`

After running above command, I got the following file.

```
"ssh myuser@192.168.210.12 -i /Documents/my_key"
"ssh myuser@192.168.210.13 -i /Documents/my_key"
"ssh myuser@192.168.210.14 -i /Documents/my_key"
"ssh myuser@192.168.210.15 -i /Documents/my_key"
"ssh myuser@192.168.210.16 -i /Documents/my_key"
"ssh myuser@192.168.210.17 -i /Documents/my_key"
"ssh myuser@192.168.210.18 -i /Documents/my_key"
"ssh myuser@192.168.210.18 -i /Documents/my_key"
```

After calling `:u` and then same replace, I got the following:

```
"ssh myuser@192.168.210.12 -i "ssh myuser@192.168.210.12 -i /Documents/my_key"/Documents/my_key"
"ssh myuser@192.168.210.13 -i "ssh myuser@192.168.210.13 -i /Documents/my_key"/Documents/my_key"
"ssh myuser@192.168.210.14 -i "ssh myuser@192.168.210.14 -i /Documents/my_key"/Documents/my_key"
"ssh myuser@192.168.210.15 -i "ssh myuser@192.168.210.15 -i /Documents/my_key"/Documents/my_key"
"ssh myuser@192.168.210.16 -i "ssh myuser@192.168.210.16 -i /Documents/my_key"/Documents/my_key"
"ssh myuser@192.168.210.17 -i "ssh myuser@192.168.210.17 -i /Documents/my_key"/Documents/my_key"
"ssh myuser@192.168.210.18 -i "ssh myuser@192.168.210.18 -i /Documents/my_key"/Documents/my_key"
"ssh myuser@192.168.210.18 -i "ssh myuser@192.168.210.18 -i /Documents/my_key"/Documents/my_key"
```

Again, I call :u and replace, it gives following output

```
"ssh myuser@192.168.210.12 -i "ssh myuser@192.168.210.12 -i "ssh myuser@192.168.210.12 -i /Documents/my_key"/Documents/my_key"/Documents/my_key"
"ssh myuser@192.168.210.13 -i "ssh myuser@192.168.210.13 -i "ssh myuser@192.168.210.13 -i /Documents/my_key"/Documents/my_key"/Documents/my_key"
"ssh myuser@192.168.210.14 -i "ssh myuser@192.168.210.14 -i "ssh myuser@192.168.210.14 -i /Documents/my_key"/Documents/my_key"/Documents/my_key"
"ssh myuser@192.168.210.15 -i "ssh myuser@192.168.210.15 -i "ssh myuser@192.168.210.15 -i /Documents/my_key"/Documents/my_key"/Documents/my_key"
"ssh myuser@192.168.210.16 -i "ssh myuser@192.168.210.16 -i "ssh myuser@192.168.210.16 -i /Documents/my_key"/Documents/my_key"/Documents/my_key"
"ssh myuser@192.168.210.17 -i "ssh myuser@192.168.210.17 -i "ssh myuser@192.168.210.17 -i /Documents/my_key"/Documents/my_key"/Documents/my_key"
"ssh myuser@192.168.210.18 -i "ssh myuser@192.168.210.18 -i "ssh myuser@192.168.210.18 -i /Documents/my_key"/Documents/my_key"/Documents/my_key"
"ssh myuser@192.168.210.18 -i "ssh myuser@192.168.210.18 -i "ssh myuser@192.168.210.18 -i /Documents/my_key"/Documents/my_key"/Documents/my_key"
```

However, when I remove `~` from the pattern (i.e. use this `%s/\(192.168.210.[0-9]\+\)/\"ssh\ myuser@\1\ -i\ \/Documents\/my_key\"/g`), then it behaves expected.

What is the reason for this unusual replace behaviour on `~`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `:h :s`

```
magic   nomagic   action   
  ~   \~      replaced with the {string} of the previous substitute  s~
 \~    ~      replaced with ~                                         s/\~
```

Applied to your substitute expression, the `~` gets replaced with the string of the previous substitute.

Comment: This really confused me when I was substituting for bash regexps :) (`=~` operator)